# How to access object's parent's propertie, from his event function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, parent

I have dynamically created `Sound` object

```
var     files:Object={};
files["file1"]={};
files["file1"]["snd"]=new Sound();
...... //url etc
files["file1"]["id"]='01'; //that's important
files["file1"]["snd"].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);

function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void 
//// somehow I need to get the `id` property of its parent
}
```

I tried

```
var localRef:Object = event.target as Object;
var localRef:Object = event.target.parent as Object;
```

But it throws error.
So I need to get the `files["file1"]["id"]` from the `onSoundLoaded()` function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly answering your question, there is no hierarchical relationship between your "snd" object and your "file1" object.  The parent keyword is for display object hierarchy.

You'll have to iterate over the files object to find your match:

```
//in the sound loaded function
for(var f:Object in files){
    if(f["snd"] === event.currentTarget){
        var myId:String = f["id"];
        //do something with the id

        break; //don't keep looping
    }
}
```

---

To go beyond the scope of your question a bit, it would indeed be much cleaner and easier to use a custom class/model that encompasses all the properties you need that relate to that one sound.  Something like this for example: (a file next to your swf/fla called `MySound.as` containing the following:

```
package {
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class MySound extends Sound {
        public var id:String;

        public function MySound(id_:String, stream:URLRequest, context:SoundLoaderContext):void {
            id = id_;
            //call the original constructor method for Sound
            super(stream, context);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
//use a vector/array instead of an object
var sounds:Vector.<MySound> = new Vector.<MySound>();

var sound:MySound = new MySound("01");
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);

//add to sound array
sounds.push(sound);

function onSoundLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var sound:MySound = MySound(e.currentTarget);

    trace("My ID: ", sound.id);
}
```

Depending on what you're doing, you could listen and respond to the complete event (loaded) inside your MySound class further abstracting it out.

Comment: That's exactly what I managed to achieve up to this moment ))

Comment: there's another option to create class that extends `Sound` class. I tried to make this package but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Yes, that would be much cleaner.

Comment: I tried `files["file1"]["snd"]=new MySound();` but it doesnt even envokes onComplete event. So let it be in loops as the plan `A`, because it's too much work to rewrite code for vector. Anyway, thanks. If you want I can start bounty for hundred points and pick your answer for your efforts to help me.

Comment: You are using the load method later yes?   For a complete event to happen you need to actually load a sound file.   `new Sound()` doesn't actually load anything.   I don't need bounty, save your rep for when your not getting the answer you need.

Comment: yes I use `.load()` and so on. But with `files["file1"]["snd"]=new MySound();` it doesn't work. With `...=new Sound()` works fine. I dont know why.